# Canvas.drawBitmap() ignoring the tile mode of the paint

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to draw subparts of a bitmap, but at a different size. If the size is bigger than the source rectangle in the bitmap, then I want that section of the bitmap to tile to fill the destination area. However, instead of getting tiled they are getting stretched.

I set up all the variables as follows:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
Rect srcRect = ...
Rect dstRect = ...
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setShader(new BitmapShader(b, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

And then in the `draw()` method I draw as follows:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(b, srcRect, dstRect, p);
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I draw `srcRect` to `dstRect` such that my subpart of the bitmap gets tiled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered the problem, put succinctly: shaders on bitmaps don't work that way.

To draw a rectangle tiled with a specific `Bitmap` you have to use `Canvas.drawRect()`, with a `Paint` that has a `BitmapShader`. However, Android dev can't ever be as simple as that.

First you have to cut out the `srcRect` to a separate `Bitmap` (caching this somewhere since I don't think this is a cheap operation), like so:

```
Bitmap t = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, srcRect.left, srcRect.top, srcRect.right-srcRect.left, srcRect.bottom-srcRect.top);
```

Then you have to create the `Paint` and the `BitmapShader`:

```
BitmapShader bs = new BitmapShader(t, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setShader(bs);
```

Then you can finally draw to the destination rectangle, but first you have to set up a translation matrix for the shader or else it won't start from the correct place and might bugger up completely if your tile mode is `CLAMP`:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postTranslate(dstRect.left, dstRect.right);
p.getShader().setMatrix(m);
canvas.drawRect(dstRect, p);
```